# How to use android classes inside libgdx project?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I just started to learn libgdx engine and I'm a little confused. Until now I've coded all my apps in a project which included android library, but this project is using the "normal" java library (but it can be run on PC and I've started it on android too).

Actually what I'm asking is how to use android classes inside this libgdx project. For instance, I would like to use dialog class or show Toast when game is finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by using the Facade design pattern, as explained in the [libgdx documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code).